# Can exist a best practice/way to load dynamic class at php?

Tags: php, class, load

Having a main class where any code has access, can some code similar, but with a best practice to load dynamic class?

**candidate code:**

```
static public function __callStatic($mtd,$arg){

    // using spl_autoload_register()
    $class = '\\framework\\libs\\'.$mtd;  

    $inst = new $class($arg);

}
```

**syntax:**

```
main::dinamicu($data);
```

Comment: I think this is a great question, but the wording needs work. I think I know what OP is asking, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Second that. I don't completely understand the question.

Comment: OP, can you try clarifying your question? It's clear you're not a native English-speaker, but we would appreciate any edit that would help us better understand what you're asking.

Comment: I ask this, because I see around web magic functions like __call()/__callStatic/... are slow.
And, can exist other way to do the same, but in a better approach

Comment: I don't understand why this would need to be a __callStatic method. From your example, it could be a function `create_dynamic_class($class_name, $arg)`, called as `create_dynamic_class('dinamicu', $data)`

Comment: create_dynamic_class() ?

Answer (score 2):

I use a Inversion of Control container for this situation.

I start with a facade class:

```
class IoC
{
  private static $container;

  public static function Initialize ( IContainer $Container )
  {
    self::$container = $Container;
  }

  public static function Resolve( $type, array $parameters = array() )
  {
    return self::$container->Resolve( $type, $parameters );
  }
}
```

Then, im my bootstrapper, I initialize the facade class with a Dependency Injection container:

```
$container = new Container();
$container->Register( 'Logger', function() { return new Logger('somefile.log'); } );
IoC::Initialize ( $container );
```

Then somewhere in my code, when I want to get a object:

```
$log = IoC::Resolve( 'Logger' );
```

By using this approach I am completely free in how I implement my dependency injection container. I can change it in any way, without breaking code in my application.

I can test the container with no statics al all, just by creating a new Container.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

Since you have mentioned "best practices", assuming that you are talking about something similar to the Service Locator Pattern (which is your `main::dinamicu($data);`), [some would argue](http://youtu.be/RlfLCWKxHJ0) that this is not a good pattern when the assumption is test driven development. Instead of the service locator, the best would be a dependency injection container.

In some ways similar to a factory class, the container will take care of the classes instantiations. To get a clear idea about and see examples on how to deal with the objects creation, see the example below (Symfony Service Container):

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/13/introduction-to-the-symfony-service-container

(The symfony service container, in spit of the adoption of a dependency injection container, it's still used as a service locator on the controllers, as in the code you have posted)